# Access SQL Server Configuration Manager on a remote server

Tags: sql-server, configuration-manager, windows-server

I am trying to add a traceflag as a startup parameter to a distant SQL Server 2016, installed on a Windows 2016 core server and I am following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-connect-to-another-computer?view=sql-server-2017)

At this point in the document:

> In the console tree, expand Services and Applications, and then expand
>   SQL Server Configuration Manager to manage the remote computer's
>   services.

There is no SQL Server Configuration Manager here.

[image]

- Is this a permissions issue?
- Does anyone know what permission needs to be added and where so I can see SQL
  Server Configuration manager under Services and Applications?
- Does core have anything to do with this?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: Do you have SQL Server installed on the local server?  If you choose add/remove Snap-In in MMC do you see an entry for "SQL Server Configuration Manager"?  I'm not sure which installation component installs the SQL Server Configuration Manager component, but it has to be installed locally.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, SQL is definitely installed on the remote server because I am able to connect to it via SSMS. On the jump server, in the Add/remove snap-in I don't see SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, for info, I am able to manage the remote computer via Computer management. I just don't have access to SQL Server Configuration manager.

Comment: The Computer Management snap-in comes with Windows. The SQL Server Configuration Management snap-in is part of SQL Server.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I was over complicating things, and just remembered that there are scripts to add startup parameters with PS.

Answer (score 1):

All I wanted to do was add a startup parameter to SQL Server and to do that, I can use this [script](http://www.erichumphrey.com/2011/03/change-sql-startup-parameters-with-powershell/).

1. **Copy the script to the remote server**
2. **Connect to the remote server on powershell**

   Enter-PSSession -ComputerName some_server_with_sql  -Credential some_user
3. **Add the Traceflag startup parameter**

   [some_server_with_sql]: PS C:\Scripts> .\AddStartupParameters.ps1  '-Tsome_trace_flag_number'

And you are done,

4. **Then to check, you can run this SQL query**

   SELECT * FROM sys.dm_server_registry WHERE registry_key LIKE '%Parameters'

[image]

Et Voilà as the French would say.